# How to update encapsulating SwiftUI View from MKMapView didSelect annotation

Tags: ios, swiftui, mapkit

What is the appropriate way to push an update to the encapsulating SwiftUI View from within an MKMapKit didSelect annotation delegate?

```
struct CompoundView: View {
  @State private var selected: MKAnnotation?
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      MapView(annotations: annotations, selected: $selected)
      if let selected = selected {
        PopUpView(selected)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`MapView` is implemented as a `UIViewRepresentable` with delegates:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
  subject.selected = view.annotation // subject is the controller's reference to the MapView wrapping MKMapView 
}
```

Passing a callback to the delegate that updates the state of `CompoundView` causes XCode to fire a `Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.` It also prevents the annotation pins in the MKMapView from being visibly selected (the pin icon doesn't grow the first time it is tapped).

Similarly, passing a binding from `CompoundView` to `MapView` seems be problematic as the issue where the pin icon doesn't grow when tapped persists. I'm assuming due to the parent View being rebuilt as the state changed.

I've tried wrapping the delegate logic in `DispatchQueue.main.async` calls, but without success and at this point I'm just guessing.

Is there a preferred way to feed information back to parent Views from within an MKMapView delegate call such that we're neither in a View update as well as not preventing the map annotations from animating normally when tapped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: As it turns out the root of my problem with the annotations not animating on selection was that I was constantly refreshing the annotations whenever the view updated. Adding the annotations in `makeUIView` and leaving `updateUIView` empty solved a lot of weird interactions.

```
func updateUIView(_ map: MKMapView, context: Context) {
  map.removeAnnotations(map.annotations)
  map.addAnnotations(annotations)
}
```

I was able to get both views to play nice by using an `ObservableObject`. This object would `@Published` the selected annotation to which the parent View was subscribed with `@ObservedObject` (or @StateObject). The map view then updated the annotation class member of the observable object from within the delegate call. Note that the map view does not mark the object as `@ObservedObject` as the map view shouldn't update when the model has changed (that causes the map annotations to bug out and not animate on selection and deselection).

Comment: You saved my day! I spent 5 hours trying to remove duplicates from map after updating annotations in updateUIView, the solution was 1 line: map.removeAnnotations(map.annotations)